# how to remove "result": "success" on json callback

Tags: php, json

The result of the call to the api server is a json file, which begins with this string:

```
{
    "result": "success"
    ,   "data": {"total":16080,"pageCount":161,"result":[{"packWidth":250,"itemNo"
```

How do I remove the part that I do not care? 
that is, this

```
{
        "result": "success"
        ,   "data": {"total":16080,"pageCount":161,"result":
```

The complete result is:

```
{
    "result": "success"
    ,   "data": {"total":16080,"pageCount":161,"result":    [{"packWidth":250,"itemNo":"1203945","groupItemNo":"1203945","status":1,"categoryId":105096,"packType":"Color Box","barcode":"6922833439687","modelLabel":"Color","packQty":24,"packInclude":"USB Cable, User Manual, USB Charger, Earphone, 1pcs Li-Battery, LCD Protector, Leather Case, Plastic Case","clearance":false,"id":103928,"packWeight":"12.500","price":"181.2800","packLength":400,"description":"description test","unitWeight":"0.726","packHeight":300}]}}
```

I use the PHP language

I have to remove the initial part:

```
{
    "result": "success"
    ,   "data": {"total":16080,"pageCount":161,"result":
```

and the final:

```
}}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi can you send the complete JSON, so that I can help, also please elaborate your issue.Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to strip those parts? On the API server side?

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the part you are not interested in? How do you use the interesting part?

Comment: I have to turn the part that interests me in csv with ";"separator

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use part of a JSON to populate a CSV file, then parse the json using `json_decode` method and access the necessary information.

Try something like this:

```
var jsonObject = json_decode(myJson);
var interestingPart = jsonObject.data.result;
```

You can now access the data in an Object manner. Or if you want to get a json back from it, then use:

```
var interestingJson = json_encode(interestingPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it should work

```
preg_replace("/^.*?:(?=\w*\[) | (\w*}\w*}\w*$)/", "", $str);
```

Edit: i wrote this before I knew of json_decode, you should really use the json functions like suggested in fazovskys answer.

Comment: But with more complex problems it might make sense to use a json parser

Comment: I reported this error

PHP Warning:  preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ]

I might be wrong script in php

Comment: Even with problems as simple as this it makes sense to use a json parser.

Comment: Hi, how can I write the script in php, to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Definitely not the right approach, sorry. Parsing json with a regex is a losing game, the same as parsing html.

Comment: @basic i know this, and i normally wouldn't do it, but I didn't know that PHP has builtin json support and I found it overkill to use a framework for such a simple task